# Cargo código HTML con php, no toma el estilo de bootstrap ¿Por qué?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Tengo un archivo php, en el cual cargo imágenes, mediante un for, escribiendo el "html".
Lo quiero cargar con estilos de columnas bootstrap, utilizando las clases "col-", pero no me toma el estilo del mismo.
Estoy utilizando el código de la siguiente manera.

```
<div class="row vertodoslosclientesimg">
    <?php for($i = 1; $i < 29; $i++):
         echo '<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente">'.
                       '<img style="width: 100%;" src="img/clientes/'.$i.'.jpg" alt="">'.
              '</div>';
          endfor;
    ?>                                        
</div>
```

Comment: que parte del estilo no te toma?

Comment: No me tomaba la parte de las columnas. Lo resolví, el for en ves de hacerlo con php, lo hago en el js y funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

el HTML pareciera estar bien, ( ejemplo generado con [php sandboox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e37e64649ac616c697afca91343e3914f786982) )

- 3 columnas en extra-small/small ( 3 * 4 = 12 )
- 4 columnas en medium/large/extra-large ( 4 * 3 = 12 )
- 12 = 100%

ref [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

```
Extra small <576px
Small       ≥576px
Medium      ≥768px
Large       ≥992px
Extra large ≥1200px
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row no-gutters vertodoslosclientesimg">
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=1" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=2" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=3" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=4" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=5" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=6" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=7" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=8" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=9" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=10" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=11" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=12" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=13" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=14" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=15" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=16" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=17" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=18" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=19" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=20" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=21" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=22" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=23" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=24" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=25" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=26" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=27" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 imgcliente"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=28" alt=""></div>
</div>
```